# Firefox WebDriver doesn't throw NoElementFoundException when calling findElement() and instead hangs?

Tags: java, selenium

I am new to Selenium and I'm running into a problem where the code snippet below throws a NoElementFoundException when run via the Chrome driver, but hangs when using the Firefox driver. The expected behavior is both Chrome and Firefox should throw the exception.

I tried embedding this in a try-catch but no exception is caught on Firefox. I searched the Internet, but can't seem to find other posts about the same issue.

```
public static String getAlbumName(){
    WebElement albumName = Browsers.getCurrentDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,...")));
    String albumNameText = albumName.getText();
    return albumNameText;
}
```

This is the exception through by Chrome:
NoSuchElementException: The element could not be found (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

I'm using Selenium 2.25.0

Any ideas why I'm seeing this discrepancy?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this is a known bug for Firefox 17 in Selenium that will be fixed in Selenium 2.27
http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=4814

Downgrading to Firefox 16 resolved my problem.

Comment: Note that Selenium 2.28 has been out for a few days now.